# how to install windows 8 in ubuntu 14.04 with dual boot option?

Tags: windows-8

I had a win 8(pre installed) in my laptop I installed ubuntu.
By mistake I installed it in my full HDD 
I would like to install win 8 again. I have my product key but do not have any installer/set up.

I have again installed ubuntu for 30GB and rest of my disk is free.
please advice

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/6321/299605

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly backup you /home directory and test the disk or use to ensure it will recover your data.
You may still have the recovery option, by say pressing f4 at the point in the boot sequence where you would press that key to access bios settings. This like all options will crap all over your ubuntu making it irretrievable to people of my or your skill level. This will hopefully give you an ms-win 8 environment which will access the Internet to download the full operating system.
If this doesn't work or is unavailable then phone yes phone Microsoft to get a bootable cd (some drives don't like dvd boot) to get you in a position for an internet download. Or you may have to part with cash to buy a full set of ms-win 8 discs . Remember if you have a contact with these discs and you may borrow those and use your license, that's not piracy.
You now have a Microsoft laptop. In microsoft's I control panel defragment and compress your drive. Consider making a d: partition for all your windows data, it helps avoid data loss during future crash recovery.
You can now reboot your machine with ubuntu installation disc in, but you need to access the bios by pressing escape,f1,f2,f12 or delete or which ever key it is for your machine. There is a bios option now on ms-win 8 machines to allow multiple operating systems (or disable Microsoft only).
Consider creating a /home partition during ubuntu install again for data loss avoidance reasons.
Ubuntu should create grub entries for ms-windows on completion.